# Why is there no TThis in C# Generics for self-referential interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics

Somewhat frequently one declares a generic Interface or abstract type: `ISomething<T>`, with the intent that you expect every implementation of the type to be of the form: `SomeClass : ISomething<SomeClass>` i.e. referencing itself.

A classic example would be `IEquatable` and `IComparable`.

Another common pattern is "paired classes". Where
`Child : IsChildOf<Parent>`
and
`Parent : IsParentOf<Child, Parent>`
because the declaration of `IsParentOf` looks like:

```
public interface IsParentOf<TChild, TParent> where TChild : IsChildOf<TParent>
```

You want to declare that the `Parent` has children ... but only *it's* kind of children:

`Dog : IsParentOf<Puppies,Dog>` and `Cat : IsParentOf<Kittens,Cat>`. But you can't inadvertantly declare `Cow : IsParentOf<Lamb, Cow>` ... because Lamb doesn't implement `IsChildOf<Cow>`

But note that the intent is that in the line `Parent : IsParentOf<Child, Parent>` ... the second generic parameter is ***always*** expected to be the type being declared.

So one could imagine a new Typing keyword `TThis` such that `IsParentOf` becomes:

```
public interface IsParentOf<TChild> where TChild : ChildOf<TThis>
```

---

*Question 0: Am I right in thinking that this concept doesn't exist in C# (nor anything similar)*

Question 1: Is there any particular reason that it *couldn't* exist?
i.e. that the idea doesn't actually make sense in certain cases / couldn't actually do what I'm imagining the way.

Or is this simply the classic "features don't exist until someone expends the time and resources to *make* them exist ... and this feature hasn't warranted the effort (so far)"?

Comment: In 22 years of doing C#, I have never encountered what you called "paired classes". Do you have any real world examples, where this would be neccessary or even common?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11773)?

Comment: Besides that having a class for "small" dogs and one for adults is pretty strange, IMHO. What are you doing when your `Puppy` grows?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain That's not the point of the example ... the point is that these classes exist in pairs. Perhaps "Transport" and "Commuter" are better meta-classes. Trains, Cars and Bikes are all modes of transport, and they all have occupants ... but a TrainPassenger, a Driver, and a Cyclist are all very different, but exist in a 1-1 mapping.

Comment: @nvoigt my current concrete case is "A variety of different business object representing journeys ... each of which has a collection of legs. The different types of journeys have some things in common and other things that are unique to the type of journey. The different types of legs have some things in common and other things that are unique to the legs of this type of journey".

Comment: @Sweeper. Yes, I believe so. I haven't read the whole thing, but it looks like exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Sweeper I would happily accept an answer of "no it doesn't exist. But yes it definitely could. Citation: it has been proposed and discussed here." (Probably linking to both your link and the other version in csharplang, linked at the bottom of the thread: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/169 )

Comment: Can you show some specific examples about the usage of "paired classes"? If 2 classes have a 1-1 mapping, in my knowledge you don't need generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking that this concept doesn't exist in C#

This does not exist as a language feature. You cannot ask the language to enforce users to actually put the implementing type as the type argument of an interface. In your `IsParentOf` example, I could write:

```
class SomethingElse : IsParentOf<Puppies, Dog>
```

even if an additional constraint were added to `TParent` (this is known as the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern))

```
public interface IsParentOf<TChild, TParent> 
    where TChild : IsChildOf<TParent>
    where TParent: IsParentOf<TChild, TParent>
```

Because `Dog` indeed implements `IsParentOf<Puppies, Dog>`.

There was an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11773) raised about adding a `: this` generic constraint so that this can be enforced, which led to [this proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/169).

It is definitely *theoretically possible* to implement this - Swift has the `Self` type, and to my knowledge Rust and Scala also has something similar. Figuring out the details of how this feature would interact with existing C# features is the hard part though, as always :)

Comment: And not just existing C# features -- though we C# users like to gloss over it, the .NET Framework is the basis for quite a few other languages as well. :P This feature would almost certainly require runtime changes.